# How do I install "Perl/Tk Debugger" on Windows 7?

Tags: installation

Trying to install the "[Perl/Tk Debugger](http://ptkdb.sourceforge.net/)" on Windows 7 -- and for the life of me I'm unable to figure out what I need to do to install and run this application..

The requirements appear to be:

- [Perl](http://www.perl.org/get.html) 5.004 or above
- [Tk](http://cpan.perl.org/modules/by-category/08_User_Interfaces/Tk/)800.021 or above

I've got Perl 5.12.2 (from ActiveState) installed; confirmed by going to the Windows commandline and entering "perl -v".

What I have no idea about is the "Tk800.021" requirement; meaning if it's already present, and if not, what to do.

---

ANSWER:

```
ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/Devel-ptkdb.ppd
```

Comment: My advice is: `Skip ActiveState altogether` use [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) instead. It comes with a working CPAN environment so that you don't have to rely on what ActiveState provides for you.

Comment: @Nifle: +1 Is ActiveState's Perl distribution ActivePerl required to run ActiveState Komodo, and if so, is it possible to run Strawberry Perl and ActivePerl? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've tried running the debugger and it doesn't work, you can try installing the latest version of the [Tk module](http://search.cpan.org/~ni-s/Tk-804.027/) from the ActiveState package manager.

Comment: +1 Thanks, "ppm inst Tk" worked -- but "ppm inst Ptkdb" gave me an error, and since I've this is only the second ppm inst I've ever done, really not sure what's wrong -- any suggestion, posted the WIN-CMD and resulting errors in my questions description under <Error on "ppm inst Ptkdb"> -- again, thanks!!

Comment: @blunders, do ActiveState have 'Devel::ptkdb' in their package manager?

Comment: figured it out, "ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/Devel-ptkdb.ppd" did the job -- thanks for your help!